# How to print/save as PDF React Native component?

Tags: react-native, pdf, printing, pdf-generation

I am trying to print/save as PDF a React Native screen from my application. Is there any Node dependency that can be used for this? Another alternative would be to convert React Native component to HTML and then save it as PDF, but I could not find any library to convert from React Native to PDF.

Thank you!

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. Did you find any solutions?